# Parallel for loop in Qt

Tags: qt, ubuntu, boost-thread

I want a sample code which do parallel for loop in Qt and Linux. Should I add boost library? Any sample code which train me how should I write parallel for loop in Qt is great. in a way I call a method in parallel.

Comment: What do you mean? If you need concurrent algorithms without mutlithread  primitives so you should read http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent-index.html

Comment: Thanks it was helpful. I think QtConcurrent::run() is useful for me. But i don't understand it completely how can I call this function simultaneously on multi thread for different input.